# Implement inheritence in ASP.Net MVC6 Identity framework

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently working on a ASP.Net 5 / ASP.Net MVC 6 application. I am using EntityFramework 7 as ORM framework, and the Code-first approach.
In my model, I have the following:

- An `AppUser` class, which inherits from `IdentityUser<int>`. `IdentityUser` is provided through `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package, and allows one to inherit from the provided class, by specifying the data type from primary keys, and, of course, add custom fields to it. Everything is working fine with it (database schema, inserts, ...)
- A `Person` class, which inherits from the previous, and adds some app-specific fields and logic. Basically, my idea is that every Person in my app is a potential user, but not every user needs to be a Person.

For all my model objects, I implemented a **generic repository** approach, which basically implements generic CRUD operations for every model class, and allows one to override generic methods for specific domain classes.

But for the AppUser class, ASP.Net Identity framework comes with its own repository, which basically allows one to add a user, add roles to user, checks unicity of logins, etc...

My question is : how can I use these two repositories together, so that when I add a `Person`, it creates a `AppUser` through the Identity framework repository, and then stores the field of my custom `Person` within the same database record ?

Notice that inheritence of Person on AppUser has been resolved by code-first as single table inheritance : the same table stores AppUser and Persons, and a discriminant field was generated.

Comment: If you're going to couple that tightly to Identity, just have your application context inherit from IdentityDbContext.

Comment: This is already the case. The question is, how can I use my repository methods (e.g. the `Add<T>(T entity)` method, which adds an entity to the context) and in the same time, the UserManger class provided by AspNet Identity framework.

Comment: Well, it finally happened that having every person being a user in my app would be an unneeded feature, so I changed my design so that I have now implemented inheritance by composition (Person no longers inherit from AppUser, but has a optional field User). Thus, I still think the question is interesting, and am curious to see how you guys may have implemented this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a custom manager class which extends the usermanger class provided by Identity framework. This new CustomUserManager class will have all the functions of UserManager class, plus the new ones which you want to implement for adding a Person

Comment: Good idea, I inherit the built-in UserManager, implement my CRUD interfaces and inject the required dependencies, and that all should do the trick. Don't know why I didn't come up with this simple idea of building a class on top of both things to get working together !